# Rails Internationalization with javascript variable

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, internationalization

I am trying to use rails translation with a dynamically changing javascript variable. Here what I mean;

```
var free_over_text = imp_date_info[1] #e.g. "31-12-2016"
var free_over = "<%= t('cancellation.free_can', :date => "free_over_text") %>";
```

then I am trying to send free_over_text to free_over as a translation variable. What I see it takes it as a string.

[image]

What is the best way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Use [I18n.js](https://github.com/fnando/i18n-js) gem for javascript string translations.

https://github.com/fnando/i18n-js

Thanks